# How to open a html table file into a (string)grid using Lazarus?

Tags: html, file, freepascal, lazarus, tstringgrid

I'm new here so feel free to give feedback on my way of asking.

For a project at school I need to open html files with tables in a stringgrid using Lazarus. My teacher said I need to use `pos` to locate the html tags, and using `<th>` and `<tr>` I should be able to define the rows and columns, but I find it very difficult.

I'm not that far with this problem, I'm stuck at an early step. I'm trying to look if my `pos` is working, but it doesn't really. My idea: clicking on `Button1` will open `OpenDialog1`. Then I choose a html file and my program will search for the text in `Pos('<th', filename)` (see the included code). The position of that text will be put in `Label1`.

I get this error:

`unit1.pas(46,30) Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 2: Got "TStringList", expected "Variant"`

So my subquestion is: How can I use `pos` in a file?

This is the code I use. Feel free to ask and give feedback. Thanks in advance!

```
procedure HtmlToGrid(Grid: TStringGrid; const FileName: string; Sender: TObject);
var
  TextFile, Line: TStringList;
  Row: Integer;
  Col: Integer;
  prob: Integer;
begin
  Grid.RowCount := 0;  //clear any previous data
  TextFile := TStringList.Create;
  Textfile.LoadFromFile(filename);
  prob := Pos('<th', TextFile);
  if (Sender is TLabel) then
    TLabel(Sender).Caption := IntToStr(prob);

end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var filename : string;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then begin
    filename:= OpenDialog1.FileName;
    HtmlToGrid(database, filename, Label1);
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Not sure I follow the logic of your code.  Why would the **filename** contain '<th'?  None of my HTML files do.  Surely, you should be processing the **contents** of the file, rather than its name?

Comment: @MartynA You're completely right. That problem is solved indeed, I will change my question. I changed the place to search for '<th' because I cannot use _Pos_ on a TStringList, which I do need to paste the file in, right?

Comment: Once you've loaded a file into a TStringList, the contents of the TStringList are accessible as a sstring via its Text property, so you can do something like P := Pos('<th', MyStringList.Text).  But possibly, you want to process the file line by line, which you can do  using the TStingList's Strings property  as in S := MyStringList.Strings[Index].  Be aware that the Strings property is zero based, so the first list is MySTiungLIst.Strings[0].  It's well worth spending half an hour reading up on TStringList in the online help.

Comment: @MartynA Thank you!! That's exactly what I want!

Comment: I will put what I said into an answer.  Give me a few minutes ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point that's causing you difficulty, I think, is not being aware that once
you've loaded a file into a TStringList, the contents of the TStringList are accessible as a sstring via its Text property, so you can do something like

```
var
  P : integer;
[...]
P := Pos('<th', Textfile.Text).
```

But possibly, you want to process the file line by line, which you can do using the TStringList's Strings property as in

```
S := MyStringList.Strings[Index].
```

Be aware that the Strings property is zero based, so the first list is MyStringLIst.Strings[0].

You could process your TextFile contents line-by-line like this

```
var
  i : Integer;
[...]
  for i := 0 to TextFile.Count - 1 do begin
    if Pos('<th', TextFile.Strings[i]) > 0 then 
      { do something }
  end;
```

Btw, its best to give your variables a name which reflects their type, and 'TextFile' is a bit misleading for something that's actually a TStringList, so the name 'StringList' might be preferable to 'TextFile'.

It's well worth spending half an hour reading up on TStringList in the online help.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'm sorry I can't vote your answer because I'm too young on this site...

Comment: No I mean I can't because this question was my first one...

Comment: See my answer from a while ago

Comment: Thanks! Searching for a button is very difficult... I've accepted it